# How come I can edit a question without review but I can't approve an edit alone?

Tags: discussion

Why can I edit a question on my own without it having to be reviewed but when I review someone else's edit it still needs two more approvals?

Thanks!

Comment: Technically you can.  Improve edit will let you add to the edit and the insta-approve it.